# PowerShell to loop through Dirs and delete folders

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following folder structure on a Win machine:

```
PSTest
   -- Folder1
      -- Bin
      -- OBJ
   -- Folder 2
     -- BIN
     -- OBJ
   -- Folder 3
     -- BIN
     -- OBJ
```

I need a PS script that will loop through and delete the BIN and OBJ folders in all folders.  Both folders will have files but I do not care.  I need all of them deleted.

So far, I am able to loop through the first level of folders but get stuck hitting the next one, looking for the folder.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: "So far, I am able to loop through the first level of folders but get stuck hitting the next one" - you forgot to post your code :)

Comment: Please show us what you already got

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.
Its a function where you give the root folder as parameter. In the function the script then searches first for BIN folders in the root folder recursively and then searches for obj folders in the root folder recursively. If the directory has been found the directory will be deleted.

```
$rootFolder = "C:\temp\ps"  #Update this with your actual root folder path
#Function to recursively delete folders
function Delete-BinAndObjFolders {
    param (
        [string]$folderPath
    )
    
    if (Test-Path -Path $folderPath) {
        $binFolder = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath "BIN"
        $objFolder = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath "OBJ"
        
        if (Test-Path -Path $binFolder) {
            Remove-Item -Path $binFolder -Force -Recurse
            Write-Host "Deleted: $binFolder"
        }
        
        if (Test-Path -Path $objFolder) {
            Remove-Item -Path $objFolder -Force -Recurse
            Write-Host "Deleted: $objFolder"
        }
        
        $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Directory
        foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
            Delete-BinAndObjFolders -folderPath $subfolder.FullName
        }
    }
}
#Start the deletion process from the root folder
Delete-BinAndObjFolders -folderPath $rootFolder
```